# Wordpress theme not working on localhost

Tags: php, wordpress

I just installed WordPress locally (XAMPP) and added some plugins and using the tesseract theme. When I try to work on the website locally, I get a long list of errors but these errors disappear when am using the internet.

The errors:

> Warning: fopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\TESSERACT\functions.php on line 1255
>
> Warning: fopen(https://s3.amazonaws.com/tesseracttheme/banner/admin_message.csv): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\TESSERACT\functions.php on line 1255
>
> Warning: feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\TESSERACT\functions.php on line 1256
>
> Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\TESSERACT\functions.php on line 1257
>
> Warning: feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\TESSERACT\functions.php on line 1256

This is what I have on functions.php

```
function readCSV($csvFile){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because theme try to open files on remote server. That`s why you need an internet connection.

Comment: To remove internet connection dependency you need download all of remote .csv files (you can find them in error messages) to your local server. Then you should to find and replace remote files path to local files path in theme source code.